# Подключение к базе данных ( php 5.5 )

Tags: php, mysql

Сейчас у меня подключение к базе данных выглядит так:

```
const HOST     =  "localhost";
const DBNAME   =  "test";
const USERNAME =  "test";
const PASS     =  "test";

$connect = mysql_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASS);
$dbselect = mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $connect);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

И простой запрос в базу:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product` LIMIT 10");
```

Все хорошо работает когда версия `php 5.3`, а когда версия `php 5.5` тогда постоянно показывается предупреждение вверху страницы:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   /home/2969327/public/config/config.php on line 6

Ето означает что `mysql_connect()` устарела, я смотрел на `mysqli()`, но не могу понять, что кроме подключения к базе данных нужно менять все запросы. Если можно, покажите пример на простом запросе к базе данных.

Answer (score 1):

Расширение mysql устарело. Используй вместо него [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Да, нужно менять все функции `mysql_` на `mysqli_` и советую сразу сделать обертку к БД типа `my_connect()`, `my_query()` или используйте какой-нибудь фреймворк.

Comment: @saturn, используйте PDO: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
$connect = mysqli_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASS);
$dbselect = mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $connect);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product` LIMIT 10");
```

Пишите

```
$connect = mysqli_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASS,DBNAME);
mysqli_query($connect,"SET NAMES utf8");
$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM `product` LIMIT 10");
```

В версий 5.5 отсутствует mysql_select_db и в mysqli_connect четвертым параметром указываете БД. При запросе к БД первым параметром всегда указывается подключение.